# Master document / sub document chapter numberings

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2010

I have had various problems with the master document feature in the recent past (see my question history!), and have come across yet another...

Using Word 2010, I have 9 subdocuments in 1 master document.  As far I'm aware, all 9 subdocuments have the same formatting, and the same style (they were all created from the same template).  Each document has a Header 1 at the beginning of the file (a chapter heading).  Most of the subdocuments recognise that this should be incremented in the master document, so that the Chapter headings and numbers appear correctly; however, a couple of documents refuse to show the correct number for where they are in the sequence, and just show 1 - this obviously then means that all subtitles / figure captions etc in that chapter are incorrect.

It might be that the style in some of my chapters has become corrupted in someway, and that I need to copy the correct style from a chapter which does work (I'd rather do that than reformat the chapters that don't work from scratch), but I don't know how to do that :/

If anyone has *any* idea what my problem is, I'll be utterly grateful

**EDIT 1**

If I copy **all** the text from a chapter which doesn't work into 1 which does, then the issue remains; however, if I copy individual paragraphs, and edit the section heads manually, then this does seem to work.  However, I'd rather not have to do this because of various other formatting that took me a long time to get right originally, and I don't want to have to redo it in the 'new' document.

**EDIT 2**

I have copied the styles (using the Styles Organiser) from a chpater (i.e. document) which works to 1 which doesn't - and still had no luck

Comment: Hi Chris. Are you using SEQ fields for the chapter numbering?

Comment: @Adam - I think so.. when I right click on a generated number I was expecting to see 'view field code' or something similar, but I don't! How do I switch it to show the field codes?

Comment: ,you can press ALT+F9 to toggle display of field codes